# Is there a way to disable the crash reporter in Flash CS4?

Tags: crash-reports, cs4

We are trying automated builds using Flash CS4, and every once in a while the IDE will crash, and we want it to just keep on running then - but instead it halts on the crash reporter and we need to actually log into the server and click "Cancel" manually.

I can't find a setting and nothing on Google - any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Windows. And it's CS4 built-in crash reporter, not the operating systems, in case that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an OS setting, and not a Flash CS4 setting, or is it?

In Windows XP you can configure this in your control panel: http://www.techtut.com/Tutorial/Windows/44-Disabling-Windows-XP-crash-report.html

In OSX you have to run a couple of terminal commands (or install a utility): http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090902164105138

Comment: No, this is a CS4 built-in crash reporter. Sorry of that was not clear from the original question.